# What shell binary should I use for the root account on a Linux system?

Tags: authentication, operating-systems, linux

Is there a security advantage to using a different shell for the root account, either a hardened shell program, or simply a shell binary stored in a non-standard location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends. If there's a different set of attacks that can replace `/bin/bash` than some other files on your filesystem, then maybe there's a case for it. I used to make my root shell on Solaris a statically-linked `/bin/sh`. The reason was that `/usr/lib` was on a different physical disk than `/`, so in single-user mode it might not be possible to start a dynamically-linked shell. The fact that this also avoided touching any compromised shared objects was merely a side-effect.

In other words, if `/bin/bash` and your proposed alternative root shell are on the same partition, with similar permissions, there probably isn't much point. An attacker who can trojan one can trojan both.

Comment: As Graham alludes, you can keep your shell (and system libraries, and essential apps...) on a non-writable partition/medium, but simply changing the shell is unlikely to add much security.